# How can I define alkenes using graph theory?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I want to represent alkenes in a mathematical fashion but I want to make sure of what I'm writing. Here is what I tried by defining "alkenic" graphs:

Alkenic graphs are connected non-looped multigraphs where:

- nodes are of degree less than 5 (octet rule);
- there is at least a double edge and no triple or quadruple ones (edges like in bonds);
- cyclic submultigraphs with conjugated single-double edges given in any conjugation order are to be considered isomorphic (anti aromatic or aromatic isomorphism).

For example, the graphs representing "1,4-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene" and "1,2-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene" are isomorphic.

In this case I'm not taking stereoisomers into account.

Comment: [Alkene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkene) reminds me of chemistry :P

Comment: Yes it's alkene is chemistry but the problem is mathematical. That's why I've decided to post this in the maths stack exchange

Comment: You can use edge colors instead of mutigraphs if that helps, but I'm not sure of including an aromaticity model in your mathematics will work very well.